# New to GWT and Eclipse / Tomcat set up

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

I am new to GWT, and I have downloaded Eclipse R2, downloaded the plug in for tomcat and all the necessaty google plug ins. Now, I need to connect my application to a MySql database...? How should I add a MySql database into tomcat or how is it done using this?, I am familiat with MSSQL and C# Website but this is totally new. Thank you

Comment: You want to add MySql in tomcat or you just want to connect to mysql?

Comment: Well, Tomcat is the server.. I want to add a MySql database to it... how can I do this?

Comment: GWT Works on RPC mechanism so in the implementation class of the service you can have the connection of MYSQl there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the jdbc driver for mysql. You can google for it.

Comment: Well, Tomcat is the server.. I want to add a MySql database to it... how can I do this?